# How to suppress "index should be a string" type error on subclassed python enum

Tags: python, enums, mypy

The following example of accessing python `Enum` members by slice comes from its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) (where `Period` happens to be an `Enum`):

```
list(Period)[:2]
```

When subclassing `Enum`, I thought it might make sense to permit a syntax that skips the wrapping in `list` (i.e. make the syntax for using my subclass more consistent with the syntax for accessing members of a `list` or `tuple`):

```
import enum

class MyEnumMeta(enum.EnumMeta):
  def __getitem__(self, indexOrSlice):
    if isinstance(indexOrSlice, (int, slice)):
      return list(self)[indexOrSlice]
    else:
      return enum.EnumMeta.__getitem__(self, indexOrSlice)

class MyEnum(enum.Enum, metaclass=MyEnumMeta): pass

class Period(MyEnum):
  A = "a"
  B = "b"
  C = "c"

print(Period["A"])
print(Period[1])    # type: ignore[misc]
print(Period[:2])   # type: ignore[misc]
```

Although this seems to execute fine, `mypy` is raising the following error unless I append `# type: ignore[misc]` to every line that attempts to use the "more condensed" syntax (which makes the syntax actually *less* condensed):

> Enum index should be a string

(You can search for this in the [mypy code](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/mypy/checkexpr.py), to see the relevant section)

I am uncomfortable with adding a statement that will suppress any legitimate [misc] errors that happen to occur in the same line. Furthermore, the fact that mypy went to the effort to raise this error (and that `Enum` doesn't permit the condensed syntax directly) makes me wonder whether there is some good reason why it should be impossible to access `Enum` members via integer or slice even in the way demonstrated in the `Enum` documentation.

If I shouldn't be doing what I am trying to do, can someone please explain why? Otherwise, can someone please suggest a better way to handle mypy? If mypy has made an error of failing to anticipate that the `Enum`s it encounters might actually be subclasses of `Enum` that override `__getitem__` as I propose, how do I report that error?

Comment: As an aside: using `Period["A"]` is a bit unusual - the usual (and better readable IMO) version is `Period.A`. This will also be proposed by most IDEs.

Comment: Yes -- good advice! Using dot-notation promotes autocomplete.

Answer (score 2):

If I have an enum `Foo`, like so:

```
from enum import Enum

class Foo(Enum):
    BAR = 1
    BAZ = 2
```

Then, one of the many wonderful things about `enum`s is that there are already multiple ways of accessing members of the enum. The following example is in the interactive console:

```
>>> Foo(1)
<Foo.BAR: 1>
>>> Foo['BAR']
<Foo.BAR: 1>
>>> Foo.BAR
<Foo.BAR: 1>
>>> Foo(Foo.BAR)
<Foo.BAR: 1>
```

As such, it *may* be unwise for you to override `EnumMeta.__getitem__` in the way you're doing, as it may not be what others reading your code will expect. The inbuilt feature of `enum`s is that you can access members by passing the member's name — a string — into the square brackets. Doing otherwise will violate the expectations of users of your code, and, as the MyPy error shows, it will also violate the expectations of a type checker. Explicitly converting the `enum` to a `list` outside of the class is somewhat different — the type checker, and any human readers of your code, are all well aware that `list`s can be indexed using integers or slices.

Comment: I don't actually call my subclass an "enum", and it has many behaviors that distinguish it from an enum (in addition to the ability to index by subclass or slice), so I don't think readers will think they are reading about an enum...

Comment: ...but you make an excellent point that subclasses should appear to be distinct from their superclasses, or the behavior they change could confuse readers.

Comment: @ChrisSantos-Lang, fair enough! It sounds interesting.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your changes.  Mypy has it's enum support hard-coded, though, so it won't recognize them.

Comment: I realize that you are the principle author of the python enum (PEP 435), so your feedback has special significance to me. I didn't write to you directly because you deserve respite (and because I like the idea of reaching-out to a community). Thank you for making yourself so accessible to our community.